# What is the maximum length of an ssh-banner message?

Tags: ssh, sshd

It seems that if the banner message is longer than a certain limit, no banner at all will be displayed to the client. What is either the character or file size limit?

Comment: What OS do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [protocol specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4252.txt) doesn't set any explicit limits.

I would imagine that limits do exist, in both the server as well as the client and both are dependent on the implementation rather then any standard and will require testing to verify.

> 5.4.  Banner Message
>
> In some jurisdictions, sending a warning message before
>      authentication may be relevant for getting legal protection.  Many
>      UNIX machines, for example, normally display text from /etc/issue,
>      use TCP wrappers, or similar software to display a banner before
>      issuing a login prompt.
>
> The SSH server may send an SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER message at any
>      time after this authentication protocol starts and before
>      authentication is successful.  This message contains text to be
>      displayed to the client user before authentication is attempted.  The
>      format is as follows:

```
  byte      SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER
  string    message in ISO-10646 UTF-8 encoding [RFC3629]
  string    language tag [RFC3066]
```

> By default, the client SHOULD display the 'message' on the screen.
>      However, since the 'message' is likely to be sent for every login
>      attempt, and since some client software will need to open a separate
>      window for this warning, the client software may allow the user to
>      explicitly disable the display of banners from the server.  The
>      'message' may consist of multiple lines, with line breaks indicated
>      by CRLF pairs.
>      If the 'message' string is displayed, control character filtering,
>      discussed in [SSH-ARCH], SHOULD be used to avoid attacks by sending
>      terminal control characters.